# EF Core add-migration error

Tags: entity-framework

I am doing code-first migration. My command is

> Add-migration -Name AddMyVariables

There are some error messages displayed as follows.

---

To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.

Add-migration : Exception calling "AddFromFile" with "1" argument(s): "User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))"

At line:1 char:1
+ Add-migration -Name AddMyVariables

- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException,Add-Migration

    ---

What does the message mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found. The project file, *.csproj, was not checked out from code repository and non-writable. Once the file was checked out, the error message was gone.